How to update a plot in python instead of creating a new one?
I am wondering how I could achive it, that python is not creating a new plot, whenever I am updating the plot. I want just one plot that can update its contents. I already spend a few hours now on stack overflow, Google, ChatGPT and Gemini but no solution presented seems to do the trick. Either new plots are being created or the one plot I want doesn't update itself. What am I missing here?
I am working with PyCharm and my Paython version is 3.10.
This is the Visualizer class:
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Utils import WorldModel


class Visualizer:
    def __init__(self):
        worldmodel = WorldModel.WorldModel()
        self.field_img = cv2.imread("./Visualisation/resources/field.png")
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ax.imshow(self.field_img, extent=[-5200, 5200, -3700, 3700])
        self.ax.set(xlim=(-5200, 5200), ylim=(-3700, 3700), aspect='equal')
        self.team1 = {}  # Store robot circles as matplotlib objects
        self.team2 = {}
        self.ball = None  # Store the ball circle
        for robot in worldmodel.team1positions:
            position = worldmodel.team1positions[robot]
            circle = plt.Circle(position, radius=100, color='blue', alpha=0.8, zorder=2)  # Adjust radius as needed
            print(f"Updating team 1 robot {robot} to {position}")
            self.ax.add_patch(circle)
            self.team1[robot] = circle

        for robot in worldmodel.team2positions:
            position = worldmodel.team2positions[robot]
            circle = plt.Circle(position, radius=100, color='red')  # Adjust radius as needed
            self.ax.add_patch(circle)
            self.team2[robot] = circle

        x, y = worldmodel.ballposition
        self.ball = plt.Circle((x, y), radius=40, color='black')


        #Here I have tried also self.fig.show(), plt.show(block=False) or just plt.show()
        plt.ion()
        plt.figure()
        plt.show()


    def update(self):
        worldmodel = WorldModel.WorldModel()
        plt.clf()
        for robot in self.team1:
            self.team1[robot].center = worldmodel.team1positions[robot]

        for robot in self.team2:
            self.team2[robot].center = worldmodel.team2positions[robot]

        if self.ball:
            self.ball.center = worldmodel.ballposition

        self.ax.add_patch(self.ball)

        #With this the plot is not being updated at all
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events() #Having this or not doesn't seem to make a 
        difference
        #self.fig.show()   #this creates new plots the way I expect them to be

        plt.pause(10e-10)

this is my main, where I call the update-method
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Initialize")
    ball = Ball.Ball()
    field = Field.Field(9, 6, 2.2)
    team_1 = Team.Team("Team 1", Strategy1.Strategy1())
    team_2 = Team.Team("Team 2", Strategy2.Strategy2())
    worldModel = WorldModel.WorldModel()
    worldModel.setup(ball.get_position(), team_1.get_positions(), team_2.get_positions(), field)
    for robot in team_1.robots:
        robot._world_model = worldModel
    for robot in team_2.robots:
        robot._world_model = worldModel
    rules = Rules
    end_condition = False
    visualizer = Visualizer.Visualizer()
    print("Starting simulation")
    worldModel.print()
    visualizer.update()
    #for i in range(0,10):
    while (True):
        team_1.execute_next_actions()
        ball.update_position()
        worldModel.update(ball.get_position(), team_1.get_positions(), team_2.get_positions())
        worldModel.print()
        worldModel.check_collision()
        visualizer.update()
        


I have done this in the init-Method. Or is it at the wrong place?

I figured it out: The Code is correct, but because the Plot was opened in PyCharm directly it didn't update. The plot has to be opened in a seperate window. I achieved this by going to File-> Settings -> Tools -> Python Plot and unchecking the 'Show Plots in Tool Window'- Box.
